# Hiding URL on a one page website

Tags: html, url, navigation

I have recently finished my new one page portfolio website. I am having some trouble hiding the URL of the links. 
example: when you click 'My Work' link, it takes you to the div that is located for the 'My WorK' section of the website.

So currently it reads **http://www.springalldesign.co.uk/#title-wrapper** which looks quite messy.
(**#title-wrapper** is just the name of the div of the top of that section)

I know i could just change the div to so it would instead read **http://www.springalldesign.co.uk/#mywork** but i still think it looks messy. I would just like the URL to read **http://www.springalldesign.co.uk/** no matter what link you clicked on.

Thanks in advance

[link to website](http://www.springalldesign.co.uk/)

Comment: not changing it is pretty lazy for a web developer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 101, you're setting the URL hash:

```
location.hash = target;
```

If you don't want the hash to show up, just remove this line.

Keep in mind that this would prevent deep linking.

Comment: thank you that did the trick. I am not too worried about deep linking as it is quite a small site. But it is good information to have for future projects. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you leave the hashes (#), because user can easily get particular page by direct URL (for example What I Do => http://www.springalldesign.co.uk/#whatido-title)

To get rid of hashes (#) you can change your menu's <A href's> to <A onclick's> respectively.
Keep in mind that you should also provide 'onclick' event handler to navigate properly.

Answer (score 0):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3M7kd/show/)  *(Remove `/show/` to access jsFiddle Edit page.)*

Your homepage can just display a `iframe` to your webpage.

Then, navigation at the *URL Address Bar* **never** changes.

In that jsFiddle, notice how the Address Bar is always the same.